# What is the Type of a javascript object property?

Tags: javascript, json, object

Javascript objects use a key value system (like a hash, map, or dictionary in other programming languages). The key is referred to as a property and within an object is written like this:

```
var object = { property01: value01, property02: value02 }
```

Within objects we can access the value of the property using two access methods.

```
object.property01
object['property01']
```

In the example above `property01` and `property02`:

What is the type of the variable holding the property name, and how is it stored in memory?

Comment: All ECMAScript 5 (and lower) properties are strings, though they can be accessed with dot syntax when they are valid property identifiers, as you've shown. ECMAScript 6 added [Symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol). JSON is a text-based data transmission format. Its syntax happened to be derived from some of JavaScript's literal syntax, but beyond that, it isn't tied specifically to JavaScript.

Comment: I've never heard the term "library". Did you mean "dictionary"?

Comment: Yes sorry meant dictionary, thanks @Bergi. Edited the post to reflect your comment.

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't get the question. What do you mean by "type of variable/object" that "holds" something? Are you asking about engine internals? You already seem to know how objects work - they hold a set of properties, each consisting of a name - either a string or symbol - and a value.

Comment: I guess my confusion is the type of the variable held in memory as the key. It is represented like a string but without the quotation marks. On face value it is a string but that is an assumption on my part at the moment, and I am very interested in what is happening internally inside the compiler. Somewhere it is being converted into binary code and read from that back to be displayed. There would appear to be a process that adjusts how that works to display its representation that differs from the way strings are handled.

Comment: And furthermore what is the difference between a string and a symbol in JavaScript. Perhaps I should edit the question?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly, but the closest answer I could reference is this:

> Objects are sometimes called associative arrays, since each property is associated with a string value that can be used to access it.

Source: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects

Answer (score -2):

It's a variable, but instead of being attached to the window object, it's attached to another variable.